# Can any Geth unit insta-kill in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The Atlus, Banshee, Phantom and Brute can all kill you in one hit if you are close, even at full shields and health. I have not observed such a from the Geth. Can the Pyro or Prime or any other unit kill you in melee with a single attack?

Comment: The Pyro can kill you near instantly, but I don't think that's from melee. -_-

Comment: Don't think so, in fact very few are apt to even melee aside from Hunters it seems.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: I'm well aware of that, I do mean the sort of thing where they pick you up, and you get a little mini cut-scene and then are dead, dead, dead (until the next round).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Geth do not have a unit that can insta kill.  However, this is balanced by the multiple units that have high burst damage.

- Geth Rocket Trooper
- Geth Hunter
- Geth Pyro

Also, the banshee's melee animation is quite long and can be interrupted if a biotic explosion is triggered before the impale occurs or if you had a missile launcher ready to take her out (the animation to bring out the missile launcher and to fire takes too long for you to save the party member).

Comment: I've saved more Krogan from banshees (on my Adept) than I can count on one hand. Very useful to be able to save their hides.

Comment: The Atlas isn't super quick either, so I wouldn't be surprised if a save where possible there as well, though again you'd probably have to already have the missile launcher ready.